# mklink error in visual studios/webdev

Tags: windows, windows-7, path, mklink

In my webapp i write `Process.Start("mklink", args);`. This is for testing only and the function has an if to check which os this app is running on (it will be running on my linux server) but i get an exception

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

My mklink is a system file on windows7 and vista. I suspect it isnt finding it because mklink may only be in the admin path.

How do i make it so my program can access mklink?

Answer (score 3):

`mklink` is built into cmd.exe. You would have to launch cmd.exe to access it. You could do this with `cmd.exe /C mklink`

where
`/C` = execute command and terminate.

Answer (score 2):

cmd.exe /C mklink "C:\Users\sizu\fooSymbolic" "C:\Users\sizu\foo"